# What is the meaning of “safeguarding of prospects” in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of “safeguarding of prospects” in the following context (from Mark Everard, [*The Ecology of Everyday Things*](https://books.google.com/books?id=E-UGEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22safeguarding+of+prospects%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiepeXwoM3vAhXhMn0KHcWLAJgQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22safeguarding%20of%20prospects%22&f=false) [2020])? Does it mean safeguarding or protection of the future prospects? Does it mean something to the effect of making a better future?

> And, who knows, by seeing the world differently and touching our rootedness in nature, we may enrich and inform our own lives, our ensuing decisions, and thereby also contribute to the **safeguarding of prospects** for the myriad people with whom we are unbreakably interconnected by our common ecological dependences.

Comment: Protecting future opportunities (for the .Earth's population).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could mean the future, but also the present I would say. It’s a somewhat convoluted way of saying that when we are heedless of the impact our actions have on the environment we cause ecological harm that impacts the well-being of a lot of other people.